# My data in useState gets lost when i reload my page in react

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({name:"", password:""});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to persist some state, you're better off using a mechanism like Local Storage.

Related read: [Using `localStorage` with React Hooks](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-localstorage-react-hooks/)